# Hiding Flash timeline layers for preview/publish

Tags: flash, timeline, flash-cs5

When I'm in design mode in Flash Pro, I can selectively hide layers.  However, whenever I run the movie for testing the hidden layer inevitably shows up.  Frustrating, as I want to be able to test several different layers and not have them all appear.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want layers not to be exported, turn them into "Guide" layers (right click on the layer > Guide). Hiding layers is an authoring aid only.

Comment: Can you check out my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800665/how-to-paste-object-into-all-frames-of-flash-timeline

Comment: This was particularly useful for me when having guides inside a graphic that I didn't want to show when used on the stage.

Answer (score 7):

Or, go to File > Publish Settings and uncheck "include hidden layers", if you don't see it right away, it's compressed in the "ADVANCED" tab.

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Publish settings option.  Using guide option wrongly makes application attempt to process extra logic (actual guides) and will eventually slow down the application a lot.

Comment: The question already has a marked answer, this looks more like a comment instead.

Comment: But in reality this and the previous one are the correct answers. In adobe animation, putting the layers in a guide mode to not render them no longer works.